# Angular 6 - expression has changed after it was checked error and async *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-lifecycle-hooks

How do get rid of the mentioned error when `*ngIf` directive is based on an asynchronous condition?

In my main component (`products.ts`) I am subscribed to an observable, that is a result of a user's selection, which he can make through interacting with many components (including `products.ts`). In the template of this component (`products.html`) I need to check if any products are selected and if so, display their number.

It all works perfectly, but I'd like to get rid of the error.

Product.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
      this.countProducts = this.products.length;
    });
  }
```

Product.html

```
  <span *ngIf="countProducts" [matBadge]="countProducts"></span> //if countProduct is not 0 or undefined, display the number of products
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the async pipe. (You don't even need to subscribe within the component.)

Product.ts

```
public products$ = this.productService.getProducts();
```

use the async pipe in the template:

```
<span *ngIf="(products$ | async)?.length" [matBadge]="(products$ | async)?.length"></span>
```

There is also no need to unsubscribe. The async pipe handle this, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that since I need this.products for other functions in this component as well.

Comment: This works also on other places in the component (in template).
In 99% you don't need to subscribe within the component itself. 
Just `pipe`.

Use the async-pipe in the template.

AND:
there is nothing wrong to combine this. Use the `subscribe`in component. And async pipe in the template. You get the same value.

Comment: Thank you again, although I've tried with async pipe and the result is the same - everything still works, but the error in the console persists.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you change data after angular change detection has run. It happens usually when you change data in ngAfterViewInit lifecycle. Do you run something in this lifecycle?

Comment: No, I only have ngOnInit lifecycle.